# Formatting equations to display next to one another

Tags: equations, align

I want to format my equation as follows:

x = a        y = b

x = c        y = d

Below is the actual Latex code.

```
\begin{align*}
 kx_{N-1}^2\lambda_{N-1}^2 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
 \lambda_{N-1}^2 &= \frac{m(x_N - x_{N-1})}{kx_{N-1}^2}\\
 \lambda_{N-1} &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\frac{x_N - x_{N-1}}{x_{N-1}}
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + 2k\alpha -1 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
\frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1\\
\lambda_{N-1} &= \frac{1-\alpha m}{2k^2\alpha^2}[m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1]
\end{align*}
```

I need these two sets of equations side by side. I tried putting the equation in between `/begin{equation}` and `/end{equation}` but I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I managed eventually.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 -kx_{N-1}^2\lambda_{N-1}^2 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
 \lambda_{N-1}^2 &= -\frac{m(x_N - x_{N-1})}{kx_{N-1}^2}\\
 \lambda_{N-1} &= \pm\sqrt{-\frac{m}{k}}\frac{x_N - x_{N-1}}{x_{N-1}}
 \end{split}
 \ \ \ \ 
 \begin{split}
 -\frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} - 2k\alpha +1 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
 \frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} &= 1 - 2k\alpha - m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
 \lambda_{N-1} &= \frac{1-\alpha m}{2k^2\alpha^2}( 1 - 2k\alpha - m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2)
 \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something like that?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
 kx_{N-1}^2\lambda_{N-1}^2 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 &&
\frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + 2k\alpha -1= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
 \lambda_{N-1}^2 &= \frac{m(x_N - x_{N-1})}{kx_{N-1}^2} & & \frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} = m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1\\
 \lambda_{N-1} &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\frac{x_N - x_{N-1}}{x_{N-1}} && \lambda_{N-1}= \frac{1-\alpha m}{2k^2\alpha^2}[m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1]
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect! But are these packages necessary?
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}  
    \usepackage{fourier}

Comment: Not all really. Fourier is one of the fonts I like to use (I'm fed up with Computer Modern, but that's a personal matter). `[T1]{fontenc}` is necessary for a correct hyphenation as soon as you write in a language with accented letters in which case you should not use the default Computer Modern, but Latin Modern (`usepackage{lmodern}`)… or another font, as I did.  As to geometry, it was to show margins; if you're satisfied with the default layout, you don't need it. As to `mathtools` it is a very useful  extension to `amsmath`, which you don't have to load, since mathtools does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can put those equations in `minipage`s in order to get them on one line. But for a normal `article` class, this would not fit. As we do not have an MWE of yours, I post this solution anyway.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show that it does not fit on one page.

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        kx_{N-1}^2\lambda_{N-1}^2 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
        \lambda_{N-1}^2 &= \frac{m(x_N - x_{N-1})}{kx_{N-1}^2}\\
        \lambda_{N-1} &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\frac{x_N - x_{N-1}}{x_{N-1}}
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.7\textwidth}
    \begin{align*}
        \frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + 2k\alpha -1 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
        \frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1\\
        \lambda_{N-1} &= \frac{1-\alpha m}{2k^2\alpha^2}[m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1]
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively (but shown a lot of times around here) an `alignat*`-approach:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    kx_{N-1}^2\lambda_{N-1}^2 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 & \frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} + 2k\alpha -1 &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2\\
    \lambda_{N-1}^2 &= \frac{m(x_N - x_{N-1})}{kx_{N-1}^2} &\frac{2k^2\alpha^2}{1-\alpha m}\lambda_{N-1} &= m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1\\
    \lambda_{N-1} &= \pm\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\frac{x_N - x_{N-1}}{x_{N-1}} &\lambda_{N-1} &= \frac{1-\alpha m}{2k^2\alpha^2}[m(x_N - x_{N-1})^2 -2k\alpha + 1]
\end{alignat*}
```

---

You will have to reformat your equations or drop the alignment point at the equal signs.

Comment: Why not `alignat*`?

Comment: @HarishKumar I was not sure, if it will stay with those 6 equations. If it will, it would be clearly a dupe. I will add that anyway...